# IPHONE: UIAlertView called twice in a custom function/IBAction

Tags: iphone

i have an IBAction which does some processing and within will have a few UIAlertViews (to show alerts). However it seems that the FIRST alert in the paragraph is being called TWICE (once immediately after i clicked and another time after all the other alerts has occured). Additionally, the first time the alert appears, the alert automatically closes even though i have an OK button and the user has not clicked on it. The 2nd time the alert appears, it will require the user to click on OK.

I tried moving the paragraph out from IBAction into its own function but still the problem occurs.

all the alerts in my IBAction/function are the same:

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah" message:@"blah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
```

but the other alerts function normally.

the code looks like this ("blah" is the one being called twice):

```
-(void)function {
  if (......) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah" message:@"blah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];
     for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    if (.....) {
          //do stuff
    } else {
UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah2" message:@"blah2" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
         [alert2 show];
         [alert2 release];
    }
     }
   } else {
UIAlertView *alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah3" message:@"blah3" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
         [alert3 show];
         [alert3 release];
}
}
```

please help!

Comment: its a straight forward code, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need more code to diagnose your problem. What you provide is not sufficient.

Second, I once encountered a similar problem: when a *compose an email* action is triggered by the user who didn't set up her email account on that device, I asked my app to show an UIAlertView. However, when I tested my code on a real device with such a scenario, two consecutive UIAlertViews showed, one after another, both of which are about the email account not set up issue.

I finally figured out that the iOS system will automatically show an UIAlertView when the email account is not set up while a user tries to compose an email, which is why two UIAlertViews showed up when I only expected one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well the problem is my code is rather long. and its mostly just if else and for loop statements doing stuff (which works fine as i have tested) but its the uialertview that's behaving oddly.

Comment: so i guess i am asking if anyone else had experienced this issue before where uialertview is called twice and the first time it is called, the uialertview will auto close (no one press the OK button) whereas the 2nd time it appears it requires a click to close it.

Comment: or could it be because i created the program as a view app but i  have never used the view (in interfacebuilder) and i created a window and all the action is being done on the window?